# Why "dimensions" attribute is not working on blender 2.8?

Tags: python, dimensions

This code should resize objects. It works great in 2.79, but not in 2.8.

I get this error:

> AttributeError: 'bpy_prop_collection' object has no attribute 'dimensions'

This is my code, I can't find the error:

```
   #SCALE AUTOMATICALLY

    dimX = bpy.context.scene.objects.dimensions.x
    dimY = bpy.context.scene.objects.dimensions.y
    dimZ = bpy.context.scene.objects.dimensions.z

    multiple = 5 / dimZ

    bpy.context.scene.objects.dimensions = (dimX * multiple, dimY * multiple, 5)
```

Comment: Are you trying to change the dimensions of every object?

Comment: FWIW I dispute the claim that the code posted works in any version.

Answer (score 1):

You're referring to multiple objects, which altogether have no attribute "dimensions". Each individual object has, though:

```
for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects: 
    dimX, dimY, dimZ = obj.dimensions
    multiple = 5/dimZ
    obj.dimensions = (dimX * multiple, dimY * multiple, 5)
```

Be aware that division by zero could be an issue. Also I'm not sure if all objects have dimensions (cameras?). You could add `if obj.type != "MESH" or dimZ == 0: continue` as the second line of your `for`loop.

Comment: or `obj.dimensions *= multiple`