# Scale model so distance between highest and lowest vertices are equal

Tags: scale

I have a bunch of models I made previously, and exported to obj's, all different sizes, I lose the original blend files to ransomware, but need to import those obj's into blender, and make them all the same size (ie, the distance between the topmost vertex and lowest must be equal for all the models, how can I set them all to, say, one unit?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: The answer here https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/156501/15543 sets all objects in scene's z dimension to 5. (after import the new objects are generally `context.selected_objects`)  This is different from vertex distance.

Comment: is there a way to do this without scripting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using a script, see this answer https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/156501/15543

```
import bpy
for ob in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    if ob.dimensions.z:
        ob.dimensions *= 1 / ob.dimensions.z
```

will set all selected  with z dimension, to z dimension 1.

Note this is making the vertical (z direction) distance between top and bottom verts equal, and doesn't take into account x or y location at all.

> is there a way to do this without scripting?

Equiv of this per individual object in the UI

[image]